# ¿Como saltear numeros de dos en dos? java

Tags: java

Buenas en un for debo mostrar numeros hasta el 20 y con saltos de dos, intente hacerlo pero solo saltea los numeros pares y yo quiero que salga : 2 - 5 - 8 - 11 - 14 - 17 - 20 
por el momento hice esto:

```
int num=0;
    int c=0;
    for (int i = 0; i > 0; i--) {/*para que salgan los numeros en otra orden*/

        c++;
        num=i;
        if(c==2) {
            c=0;
            continue;   
        }
        if(num==20) {
            break;
        }


        System.out.println(num);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas un for puedes definir el rango y el incremento entre cada iteracion.

Solucion

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

  for(int i=2;i<=20; i+=3){ // en la ultima seccion puedes definir si el incremento es de 2,3 o lo que tu quieras.
      System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si tu pregunta esta bien formulada pero la diferencia entre 5 y 2 son 3 numeros , osea que en realidad queres que de saltos de 3, no de 2. 
Segun como estas planteando la pregunta.

**Si queres que vaya de 2 en 2 hasta llegar a 20**

```
int num=0;

    for (int i = 0; i<=10; i++) {/*para que salgan los numeros en otra orden*/
      num = num+2; 

      System.out.println(num);
    }
```

**Si queres que te los tire en el orden que escribiste en tu pregunta entonces seria de 3 en 3**

```
 int num=0;

        for (int i = 0; i<=6; i++) {/*solo da 6 vueltas porque queres llegar a 20*/
          if(i=0){
             num=2;
          } else {
            num = num+3; 
          }


          System.out.println(num);
        }
```

Comment: Aún no podía comenzar un comentario, pero estaba editando para poner la respuesta.